# upgrading from rails 3.0.8 to 3.0.17 produces "undefined method `reputation_value_for'" for active record-reputation-system 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Everything was running great in rails 3.0.8. I am upgrading to rails 3.2 eventually but to get things ready Ryan Bates in a Railscast recommends first upgrading to the latest rails 3.0 version which is 3.0.17. After upgrading to 3.0.17 I got:

```
undefined method `reputation_value_for'
```

I am running rails in a rvm installed Ruby version 1.9.2. To be sure that it wasn't a problem with gems, I uninstalled 1.9.2 and reinstalled it. I installed the bundler gem and then ran bundle install. It still got the same error.

I then renamed the database migrations and ran rails g reputation_system. The old and new migration files were exactly the same.

Gist of full backtrace, Gemfile and Gemfile.lock [here](https://gist.github.com/3893009).

Comment: Please provide a full backtrace and any recant code from your app or your gems.

Comment: backtrace link posted in question. there hasn't been any recent changes in the code. the only gem change is the rails upgrade.

Comment: which version of activerecord-reputation-system are you using?

Comment: activerecord-reputation-system 2.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I briefly looked over the code of the gem, can it be that the method you want is now named reputation_for?

it was deprecated and replaced by reputation_for, see commit

https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/commit/552c04b0dead76cd79fb3915845b17b6a8de0cca

Comment: I don't know why upgrading rails would result in that change... did the gem version (2.0.1) remain the same after that change?

Comment: i assume you changed your bundle and therefore the gem also got updated beside rails.